# How do I store all the information of an object in an array?

Tags: java, android-studio

Can someone guide me on how I can store all the dates and statuses in aryEventDateList and aryEventStatusList? Thank you very much.

```
    try {
        aryEventDateList = new ArrayList<>();
        aryEventStatusList = new ArrayList<>();
        String logString = "";
        String deviceUId = "";
        int logLen = jsonArray.length();

        for (int j = 0; j < logLen; j++) {
            JSONObject logJsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);
            deviceUId = logJsonObject.getString("uuid");
            Date date = ISO8601.toDate(logJsonObject.getString("created_at"));
            String message = logJsonObject.getString("message");
            String[] parts = message.split(":");
            String storedMessage = outFormat.format(date) + " - " + parts[1];
            logString += storedMessage;
            aryEventDateList.add(outFormat.format(date));  // I want to store dates here
            aryEventStatusList.add(parts[1].trim());  // and statuses here

            if (j < logLen - 1) {
                logString += "\n";
            }

            String prefKey = "notification_list_" + deviceUId;
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putString(prefKey, logString);
            editor.apply();
        }
```

Comment: What specifically is your issue? It looks like you know how to add items to an array already `array.add(...);` Do you want to do it a different way, and if so, how? Do you want to have a single array? Are you getting any errors? And what types are the arrays?

Comment: I am only storing dates and statuses of one bot. There are 3 bots

Comment: Then perform the same action for all 3 bots, although you only need to create the arraylist once `aryEventDateList = new ArrayList<>();`, don't repeat that otherwise you will erase the previous list. Please edit your question to provide more information. Do the bots each have a different log, or are they all stored in the same JSON array?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do so

Comment: use TinyDB library to store.